# Не читается файл ресурсов Qt

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, resources

В программе необходимо считывать файлы текстовые файлы ресурсов по ходу её выполнения.
Вот такая конструкция не работает:

```
    Main_inf_way = ":/n/documentation/MainInfo.xml";

    QString str;
    str = readFromFile(Main_inf_way);

    ui->textEdit->setHtml(str);
}

DocumentationWidget::~DocumentationWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString DocumentationWidget::readFromFile(QString &way)
{
    QFile file(way);
    QTextStream reader(&file);
    QString result_string = "ОШИБКА";

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Ошибка работы с ресурсами программы", "Файл по пути: " + way + " невозможно открыть");
    }

    else
    {
        result_string = reader.readAll();
        file.close();
    }

    return  result_string;
}
```

Путь я получил путём нажатия кнопки "Скопировать путь в буфер обмена" в редакторе файлов ресурсов.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать через запуск qmake. Если не поможет, приложите в вопрос скриншот открытого файла ресурсов. А вообще, у вас там не опечатка ли `if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))`? Смысл ругаться, когда файл удачно открылся? :D

Comment: Вы очень большой молодец, это моя невнимательность, забыл ! поставить.

Comment: По сути, это решение проблемы, спасибо вам

Comment: Прежде чем задавать вопрос на форуме нужно было внимательно просмотреть всё